# Visual Studio rename stash

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to set the name of a stash in **Visual Studio**'s *Git Changes* window instead of standard `WIP on <branch name>`?

Comment: I think you just add a commit message when you create the stash.

Comment: Yes, it's silly, but I've never tried to put some text to 'message' box during stashing:) Please, make an answer from your comment, I'll accept it;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a commit message when you create the stash - then you will see this as a description for your stash instead of the default `wip on <branchname>`.